# Draw graphics and export with pixel precision with CoreGraphics

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, core-graphics, cgcontext

I saw few questions here on stackoverflow but none of them is solving my problem. What I want to do is to subclass `NSView` and draw some shapes on it. Then I want to export/save created graphics to png file. And while drawing is quite simple, I want to be able to store image with pixel precision - I know that drawing is being done in points instead of pixels. So what I am doing is I override `draw()` method to draw any graphic like so:

```
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {

        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        NSColor.white.setFill()
        dirtyRect.fill()

        NSColor.green.setFill()
        NSColor.green.setStroke()

        currentContext?.beginPath()
        currentContext?.setLineWidth(1.0)
        currentContext?.setStrokeColor(NSColor.green.cgColor)
        currentContext?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        currentContext?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: self.frame.height))
        currentContext?.closePath()
}
```

and since on screen it looks OK, after saving this to file is not what I expected. I set line width to 1 but in exported file it is 2 pixels wide. And to save image, I create `NSImage` from current view:

```
func getImage() -> NSImage? {
    
    let size = self.bounds.size
    let imageSize = NSMakeSize(size.width, size.height)
    
    guard let imageRepresentation = self.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: self.bounds) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    imageRepresentation.size = imageSize
    self.cacheDisplay(in: self.bounds, to: imageRepresentation)
    let image = NSImage(size: imageSize)
    image.addRepresentation(imageRepresentation)
    return image
}
```

and this image is then save to file:

```
do {
    guard let image = self.canvasView?.getImage() else {
        return
    }
                
    let imageRep = image.representations.first as? NSBitmapImageRep
    let data = imageRep?.representation(using: .png, properties: [:])
                
    try data?.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
                
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Do you have any tips of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "I set line width to 1 but in exported file it is 2 pixels wide." Retina display?

Comment: yes. `let scale = NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor` is returning 2